# ngOnchanges is triggered and geting the currentValue(it is an object) but can't access the value inside the object

Tags: javascript, angular, javascript-objects, angular-lifecycle-hooks, ngonchanges

`dragAndUpload.ts`

```
export class DragAndUploadComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() filesData: any;
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    console.log(changes.filesData.currentValue);
    console.log(changes.filesData.currentValue.files);
  }
}
```

in console:
Object {  } //when this object expand its shows like below

```
Object{
 "files": {
    "image": [
      "image_link"
    ],
    "video": [
      "video_link"
    ]
  }
 }
}
```

and the console of the `(changes.filesData.currentValue.files)` is `undefined`

**HOW CAN I SOLVE THIS ISSUE**

*Thanks in Advance*

Comment: Please create a exmaple code using stackbltz to troubleshoot more.

Comment: I suspect that the event was triggered first on initialization, but the data you were seeing is pass by reference can you try `JSON.stringify(changes.filesData.currentValue)` to detach it from being reference and see if it still the same on the value you posted.

Comment: ngOnchanges only triggers when there is a different reference. If you pass the same object, but with some modification no change will be triggered. Make a copy with spread operator and check again.